# Local Copy of Expression Engine site is not showing changes

Tags: development

When I edit the files on my local copy, like the /project/templates/default_site/main.group/layout.html file.

On my project local url the changes are not displaying, the site works but any changes I make or develop are not showing up.

Any Ideas, could it be cache? I did clear all cache multiple times.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a dynamic config bootstrap? If so (or even if not), check that your `tmpl_file_basepath` config variable is set correctly to match your local machine's path.